# How can i activate and associate slideToggle function (with JavaScriot) only for the one part i'm trying to show in a foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, php, slidetoggle

I wanna show the desc of a product whenever i click in the relative info but with my code everytime i click in a random info it shows me all the desc of all the products. Please help me.

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                  $("p.info").on('click', function () {
                  $("p.desc").slideToggle();
                });
          });
      </script>




     // the info and desc of the products are cointaned in:


     <div class="products_container">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($products as $product)
                    <li>
                        <div class="products">
                            @include('helpers/productImg', ['attrs' => 'imagefrm', 'imgFile' => 
      $product->image])
                            <p id="product_name"><strong>{{ $product->name }}</strong></p>
                            <p>{{ $product->descShort }}</p>
                            @include('helpers/productPrice')
                            <p class="info">Info prodotto</p>
                            <p style="display:none" class="desc">Descrizione: {!! $product->  
      `                     descLong !!}</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: hey Lucio, welcome to stackoverflow. i'd suggest that you use .next() instead

Comment: Thanks Avi, i tried something like $("p.info").next().slideToggle(); but it returns the same result (all the desc of all products).

Comment: try to use this   $(this).next().slideToggle();

Comment: let me know if that worked. i'll post it as answer

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's because you're using a class .desc that's why it's toggling all elements with that class. however could infer from your code that .desc is next to .info onclick event
so instead of

```
  $("p.info").on('click', function () {
              $("p.desc").slideToggle();
            });
```

you should use

```
  $("p.info").on('click', function () {
              $(this).next().slideToggle(); //element next to clicked p.info
            });
```